# SQLAlchemy SQL injection protection at core level or only at ORM level

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb, sql-injection

I am working on a function which requires to query several database tables (these are all SELECT statements), for ORM library and database driver I use `SQLAlchemy` and `PyMySQL`.

Initially I built the function entirely at **ORM level**, however I hit performance issue due to several round trips between my python application server and database server every time when running the function , since then I came up with a new approach to send multiple SQL statements in one flight to database server at **SQLAlchemy Core level**.

Here is simplified version of my new approach :

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select as sa_select
db_engine = sqlalchemy_engin_init()

def my_db_query_fn(self, user_input_1, user_input_2):
    # note that user_input_1, user_input_2 are from untrusted user input
    with db_engine.connect() as conn:
        # raw DBAPI connection for multiple result sets in one go
        dbapi_conn = conn.connection
        # cursor comes from low-level database driver, not standard SQLAlchemy class
        cursor = dbapi_conn.cursor()
        try:
            table_a = Model_A.__table__
            table_b = Model_B.__table__
            stmt  = sa_select(table_a.c.column1, table_a.c.column2
                        ).where(table_a.c.column3 == user_input_1)
            stmt2 = sa_select(table_b.c.column1, table_b.c.column2
                        ).where(table_b.c.column3 == user_input_2)
            sql_compile_fn = lambda s: str(s.compile(conn.engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})) 
            # generate raw SQL statements by running compile()
            rawsqls = list(map(sql_compile_fn, [stmt, stmt2]))
            # send all the generated raw SQL statements in one round trip
            cursor.execute(';'.join(rawsqls))
            # then retrieve each result set one after the other, this part is skipped ....
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

After testing , the code above does reduce the round trip latency, but my question is : is my new approach vulnerable to SQL injection attack. Here are what I've been considering :

- As commented in the code sample above, the function `my_db_query_fn()` necessarily  takes untrusted user inputs `user_input_1` and `user_input_2` to build all SQL statements, even all the raw SQL strings are generated by `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select.compile()` instead of directly formatting raw SQL string patterns  with the untrusted user inputs.
- the function `my_db_query_fn()` executes SQL statements by `cursor.execute()` not `conn.execute()`. The `cursor` comes from low-level database driver (in my case it is `PyMySQL`) , I don't know if that is considered as bad practice to avoid SQL injection. (Or `cursor.execute()` and `conn.execute()` are never related to that ?)
- According to [the similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870227) and [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#selecting-rows-with-core-or-orm) , the function `YOUR_MODEL.__table__.select()` in **SQLAlchemy ORM** and the function `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select(YOUR_MODEL)` in **SQLAlchemy Core** actually generate instances of the same class type `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select` , and the SELECT statement instance can be passed to either `conn.execute()` or `session.execute()` . does that implicitly mean **SQLAlchemy Core** will also check against SQL injection ?

thanks for reading, I appreciate your feedback, hints, or tips

Comment: [This warning](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sqlexpressions.html#rendering-bound-parameters-inline) seems very clear that this technique is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection.